# Add additional data to jQuery wrapped object data in $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have this working code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://www.someurl.com/callback.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: jQuery(':input[name^="option"][type=\'checkbox\']:checked, :input[name^="option"][type=\'text\']'),

    complete: function (mydata) {
        //do something with it
    }
});
```

That successfully posts back any checked checkboxes and all textboxes. But now I want to add some arbitrary data as well to this. But not sure how to format it. Basically i want to simply add my own name=value pair "test=1" so that on the callback I see it like the others. But no matter what I try, I can't see to get the syntax correct in the format it expects. not sure if I should be adding it inside the jQuery() wrap or outside.. I've tried serializing, encodeURIComponent, basic string "&test=1"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to build the parameters outside of the AJAX call, like so:

```
var params = jQuery(':input[name^="option"][type=\'checkbox\']:checked, :input[name^="option"][type=\'text\']');
params.test = 1;
params.test2 = 2;
```

Then in your AJAX call, simply use:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://www.someurl.com/callback.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: params,

    complete: function (mydata) {
        //do something with it
    }
});
```

EDIT: Typically when using jQuery to collect input, I tend to use the .each function, like so:

```
var params = new Object();
$.each('input[name^=option]', function() {
    if ((this.type === 'checkbox' && $(this).is(':checked')) || this.type === 'text' && this.value !== '') {
        params[this.name] = this.value;
    }
});
```

Then if you wish to add parameters, you'd do so either after this, or right after creating your new object.

Comment: That fixed the POST variables, but the test and test2 never made it to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot I asked this previously. It was answered correctly so I'm sharing the link:

[How can I pass form data AND my own variables via jQuery Ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933833/how-can-i-pass-form-data-and-my-own-variables-via-jquery-ajax-call/18933929?noredirect=1#comment27957662_18933929)